# canvas drag and color select

Tags: javascript, canvas, color-picker, getimagedata

So I have a color-selector in canvas. The gradient color fills a shape. The user uses their mouse to select anywhere on the histogram. Pretty standard. They can also drag the mouse anywhere in the shape. To show their location once they've made a final color selection, I added a small fillRect in black that moves along with their mouse. Now here's my problem, as they're moving the mouse occasionally the getImageData function grabs the color of the small black rect rather than the underlying gradient. To fix this problem, I offset the dot by 5px from the point the mouse contacts the gradient. It worked. However, now when they drag the mouse to the exact edge of the shape, it draws that black dot outside the boundaries and looks bad. How can I prevent this while also preventing my mouse from picking up the black sqr?

[image]

```
$colors.on('touchmove mousemove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let gradient = Ybigh.colorctx.createRadialGradient(135, 330, 160, 200, 290, 30);

    gradient.addColorStop(0,    "#84342f");
    gradient.addColorStop(0.25, "#ff5f57");
    gradient.addColorStop(1,  "white");

    colorctx.beginPath();
    colorctx.moveTo(20, 185);
    colorctx.lineTo(200, 285);
    colorctx.lineTo(200, 295);
    colorctx.lineTo(20, 400);
    colorctx.closePath();
    colorctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    colorctx.strokeStyle = "#b0aaa6"; 
    colorctx.stroke();
    colorctx.fill();
    colorctx.fillStyle = "#000000";  
    colorctx.fillRect(new_color.x-2, new_color.y-2, 2, 2);
});
```

Comment: can we see the code and result ?

Comment: This looks like you are not clearing the canvas. In order to clear the canvas you may use the context method [clearRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) before  `beginPath()`. Avoiding a problem is not solving it.

Comment: Actually, this was a bad question for SO. It was more off design problem and not really a code problem. I simply had to think about how I wanted the app to work to find a solution. Not a great for people on here. I may delete this question because I don't want to sound like a noob. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround that satisfies the requirements. Essentially, what I did was allow the user to move the mouse around and change the color without a black rect displaying and only on mouseup does the small rect appear to mark the spot. It's a bit hacky, but it does the job as far as I'm concerned.

```
$("body").mouseup(function () {

            glob.hasclicked=false;
            colorctx.fillStyle = "#000000";  
            colorctx.fillRect(glob.rectPosition.x, glob.rectPosition.y, 3, 3);


        });
```